# my code keeps saying incorrect when i create my math game

Tags: python

the question: Create a math game where random addition, subtraction, multiplication or division
questions appear and the user has determine the answer.

My code keeps showing incorrect even thou the real answer is correct in my math game.
And i want to add were the code tells the user to enter a number where it says answer_question.
what do i need to do?

```
#October 27 2022
#Kenneth Sodjahin

#imports random number
import random
#choices of operations
print("Enter A for addition:")
print("Enter B for subtraction:")
print("Enter C for multiplication:")
print("Enter D for division:")
print("Enter E for exit:")

#randomises 2 numbers
num1 = random.randrange(1,100)
num2 = random.randrange(1,100)

#defining what each operations should do
def add(num1,num2):

    SumAnswer=num1 + num2
    return SumAnswer
def subtract(num1,num2):

    SubAnswer=num2-num1
    return SubAnswer
def divide(num1,num2):

    DivAnswer=num2/num1
    return DivAnswer
def multiply(num1,num2):

    MulAnswer=num1*num2
    return MulAnswer

#asks the user to chose which operation they want
options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))

#if user enters "E" code closes
if options == 'E':
    print("Bye!")
    exit()

#loop so when A is pressed it gves random addition questions
while options == 'A':
    num1 = random.randrange(1,100)
    num2 = random.randrange(1,100)
    print("What is", num1, "+", num2, ":")
    answer_question = int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))

    #if user's answer is equal to the real answer to show correct
    if answer_question == (add):
        print("You are correct!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))

    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))
        continue

#loop so when A is pressed it gves random addition questions
while options == 'B':
    num1 = random.randrange(1,100)
    num2 = random.randrange(1,100)
    print("What is", num2, "-", num1, ":")
    answer_question = int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))

    if answer_question == (subtract):
        print("You are correct!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))

    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))
        continue

while options == 'C':
    num1 = random.randrange(1,100)
    num2 = random.randrange(1,100)
    print("What is", num1, "*", num2, ":")
    answer_question = int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))

    if answer_question == (multiply):
        print("You are correct!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))

    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))
        continue

while options == 'D':
    num1 = random.randrange(1,100)
    num2 = random.randrange(1,100)
    print("What is", num2, "÷", num1, ":")
    answer_question = int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))

    if answer_question == (divide):
        print("You are correct!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))

    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
        options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))
        continue
```

Comment: `add`, `subtract` and the other two are functions. You need to call them: `add(num1, num2)`. Right now, you're comparing the uncalled function against a number.

Comment: Thank you. How do I add the while loop so the code tells the user to enter a number where I defined answer_question? I tried it but it doesn't show the randomized numbers

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use a `while` loop for each option. Use a single loop for the whole program. Get the option, then use a series of `if/elif` statements to execute the code for that option.

You also have lots of duplicate code in each option. You can extract that out of the option processing into a single code block.

```
#October 27 2022
#Kenneth Sodjahin

#imports random number
import random
#choices of operations
print("Enter A for addition:")
print("Enter B for subtraction:")
print("Enter C for multiplication:")
print("Enter D for division:")
print("Enter E for exit:")

#defining what each operations should do

def add(num1,num2):
    SumAnswer=num1 + num2
    return SumAnswer

def subtract(num1,num2):
    SubAnswer=num2-num1
    return SubAnswer

def divide(num1,num2):
    DivAnswer=num2/num1
    return DivAnswer

def multiply(num1,num2):
    MulAnswer=num1*num2
    return MulAnswer

while True:
    #asks the user to chose which operation they want
    options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))

    #if user enters "E" code closes
    if options == 'E':
        print("Bye!")
        break

    elif options == 'A':
        func = add
        symbol = '+'

    elif options == 'B':
        func = subtract
        symbol = '-'

    elif options == 'C':
        func = multiply
        symbol = '*'

    elif options == 'D':
        func = divide
        symbol = '/'

    else:
        print("That's not a valid option")
        continue

    num1 = random.randrange(1,100)
    num2 = random.randrange(1,100)

    print("What is", num1, symbol, num2, ":")
    answer_question = int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))

    #if user's answer is equal to the real answer to show correct
    if answer_question = func(num1, num2):
        print("You are correct!")
    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
```

Comment: How does func equal more than one thing?

Comment: Because you assign it different things depending on the user's choice.

Comment: The same way that `symbol` can equal more than one thing.

Comment: Oh, last question. How would I make it show the real answer for each operations?

Comment: `print(f"You are incorrect, the correct answer is {func(num1, num2)}")`